# Reset Runtime permissions

Tags: java, android, adb, android-testing

I'm testing my app on Android 6.0 (M), and I need to reset permissions before each test. How can I do this?

I tried send adb command like this `adb shell pm reset-permissions`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "shell", "pm", "reset-permissions");
Process pc = pb.start();
pc.waitFor();
```

But this is not working for me.

**update**

Under "testing" I mean testing. `JUnit`, `Espresso`, etc.

I tried testing my app with this.

Comment: The each time you `Clean and Run` your app, the permissions should get reset too. Don't use `instant Run`.

Comment: @PrerakSola I don't use `Instant Run`. I wish it all happened automatically. And I don't want each test run to do the Clean. Because if so, it is much easier each time before you start to send the command adb.

Comment: You can't run that `adb shell` command on-device and have it work. You should be able to run it from your development machine. There should be a way to add a Gradle task that executes this command that is run before your tests run.

Comment: @CommonsWare Good idea. I tried to find a way to send a command from Gradle, but unfortunately, not found.

Comment: @PrerakSola 'Clean and Run' does not reset permissions for me in Android Studio 2.2.3 and Instant Run is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

May not have been true back when the question was asked but `adb shell pm clear <package>` seems to do this on Android 8.0.